# Dynamically changing spatial reference using ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

We have a web application that has tiled layers published in GCS.

We want to publish a replica of the layers in a different projection system such that :

When a user is at a specific zoom level, GCS based tiles are rendered. 
  However when the user zooms in, the spatial reference of tha map is changed to a different projection system and tiled published for that projection system are rendered.

We are using ArcGIS JavaScript API 3.25.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the projection of the Map.  You would have to remove/hide the first Map, then create/show another Map with the new projection. And keep track of users location, user set layer visibilities etc.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/map-amd.html